# Syntax Errors with valid jquery/ javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana

Does anyone know why Aptana 3 recognise some codes in jquery-ui's docs as errors? For instance,

```
{
        "title":
            "Accordion Widget",
        "excerpt":
            "Convert a pair of headers and content panels into an accordion.",
        "termSlugs": {
            "category": [
                "widgets"
            ]
        }
    }
```

> Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ":"

[image]

Comment: So what are the errors?

Comment: Shouldn't you `var X = {...};` inside that `script` tag? It has no meaning/function without that. Or at least pass it as a function parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your development environment is parsing the object literal as a statement block (which may be the right thing to do, as curly braces are not always considered as object literals by the Javascript parser itself).

If it does so, then the colon characters after the string literals are indeed syntax errors.

Comment: thanks. so then it must something worng in my configuration for the development environment?

Comment: @lauthiamkok, I'll go out on a limb and say you should remove that script. It only serves documentation purposes, and your environment is most probably legitimate in rejecting it. Alternately, as a quick fix, you can put a `!` operator before the first curly brace. It will force the construct to be parsed as an object literal, and your environment should stop complaining.

Comment: thanks. yes I think I should just remove that documentation folder off jqeury ui. good thinking!

Answer (score 4):

Those script blocks appear to contain JSON rather than JavaScript but they don't have a type attribute to say so (JavaScript is the default data type for a script element). As a result they are parsed as JavaScript and throw an error.

(The `{` is treated as the opening of a block instead of an object literal, `"title"` is then a string literal instead of a property name, and `:` is an error)

Comment: thanks. what should I configure so aptana recognise that then?

Comment: Configure? You could turn JavaScript syntax checking off entirely I suppose. The tool is doing the right thing, there *is* an error in that code. If I was writing that, then I'd add `type="application/json"` to the script elements (or, more likely, rethink how I was adding that data to the document in the first place).

Comment: it is a folder part of jquery's so I don't think I can just change that...thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok Adding a `type` is the correct thing to do here: this appears to be what the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html) calls a "data block" -- non-script data held inside of a `<script>` block. This practice is legal (and explicitly demonstrated in an example in the spec), but the spec requires that data blocks must specify a non-runnable `type` (like `text/plain`).

Comment: thanks. where should I add `type="application/json"`?

Comment: @lauthiamkok You should add the `type` field to the `<script>` blocks whose contents are generating errors.